# Sqlite InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: python, sqlite3

Добрый день!

В процессе выполнения при обработке на какой-то строке выпадает ошибка, строки все по структуре и типу данных одинаковые:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter__init**.py",
> line 1533, in** call__
>     return self.func(*args)   File "C:\MonitorSoft\MonitorSoft.py", line
> 199, in LoadSQL
>     CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?',
> (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0],
> option='values')[3],))
> sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding
> parameter 0 - probably unsupported
> type.

Ниже кусок кода, на который ругается:

```
def LoadSQL(event):
    con = sqlite3.connect('C:/MonitorSoft/SoftMon.db')
    CurPackets = con.cursor()
    CurFiles = con.cursor()
    CurFilesIn = con.cursor()
    curFilesPackets = con.cursor()
    CurPackets.execute('SELECT * FROM Packets WHERE PacketName = ?', (WinRedactor.Combobox.get(),))
    for RowPackets in CurPackets:
        if WinRedactor.Combobox.get() !='NULL':
            while WinRedactor.Table.selection() != '':
                CurFilesIn.execute('INSERT INTO Files (id, FilePath, FileName, Size, CheckSum) VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?)',((WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[0]), (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[1]), (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[2]),(WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3])))
                con.commit()
                    CurFiles.execute('SELECT * FROM Files WHERE CheckSum = ?', (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3],))
                for RowFiles in CurFiles:
                    if RowFiles[4] == (WinRedactor.Table.item(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0], option='values')[3]):
                        curFilesPackets.execute('INSERT INTO FilesPackets (IDFile, IDPacket) VALUES(?,?)',((RowFiles[0]), (RowPackets[0])))
                        con.commit()
                WinRedactor.Table.delete(WinRedactor.Table.selection()[0])
        con.commit()
        con.close()

BtnLoadSQL = Button(WinRedactor)
BtnLoadSQL["text"] = "LOAD SQL"
BtnLoadSQL.bind("<Button-1>",LoadSQL)
BtnLoadSQL.pack()
```

В чем может быть проблема?